# Set Hibernate session's flush mode in Spring

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-3

I am writing integration tests and in one test method I'd like to write some data to DB and then read it.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration()
@Transactional
public class SimpleIntegrationTest {

    @Resource
    private DummyDAO dummyDAO;

    /**
     * Tries to store {@link com.example.server.entity.DummyEntity}.
     */
    @Test
    public void testPersistTestEntity() {
        int countBefore = dummyDAO.findAll().size();
        DummyEntity dummyEntity = new DummyEntity();
        dummyDAO.makePersistent(dummyEntity);

        //HERE SHOULD COME SESSION.FLUSH()

        int countAfter = dummyDAO.findAll().size();

        assertEquals(countBefore + 1, countAfter);
    }
}
```

As you can see between storing and reading data, the session should be flushed because the default `FushMode` is `AUTO` thus no data can be actually stored in DB.

**Question:** Can I some how set `FlushMode` to `ALWAYS` in session factory or somewhere else to avoid repeating `session.flush()` call?

All DB calls in DAO goes with `HibernateTemplate` instance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you have Spring inject the `SessionFactory` into the test, and in the `setUp` get the current `Session` and call `setFlushMode()` on it?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Before
public void myInitMethod(){
  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.ALWAYS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class SimpleIntegrationTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private DummyDAO dummyDAO;

    @Test
    public void testPersistTestEntity() {
        assertEquals(0, dummyDAO.findAll().size());
        dummyDAO.makePersistent(new DummyEntity());
        assertEquals(1, dummyDAO.findAll().size());
    }
}
```

From applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

View the source of [TransactionalTestExecutionListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionalTestExecutionListener.html) if you have questions about how transactions work in this scenario.

You can also use [AOP (aspect oriented programming)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html) to proxy transactions.

Comment: Sorry, sufficient for what? I don't really get how this can solve the problem of having hibernate session be flushed after storing the object.

Comment: While you've annotated to be transactional, no transactions are actually being handled.  Take a look at the TransactionalTestExecutionListener class.  There's a beforeTestMethod that opens transactions, and an afterTestMethod that closes/rollsback.

Comment: I have taken a look at TransactionalTestExecutionListener class. And it documentation clearly states, that classes annotated with @Transactional will start and finish transaction around method execution and it will be rolled back if class is annotated also with @TransactionConfiguration. The methods you're mentioning are for "... to be able execute certain set up or tear down code outside of a transaction". So I guess, transaction actually handled as needed

Answer (score 0):

According to [hibernate object flushing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing), flushing occurs by default at the following points:

- before some query executions
- from org.hibernate.Transaction.commit()
- from Session.flush()

Therefore, before `dummyDAO.findAll().size();` is called, objects in session are already flushed in db. Setting FlushMode to ALWAYS is not necessary.